# Why didn't Hulk transform to Banner for 2 years?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok*, when Hulk changes into Banner he ask Thor about Sokovia, which happened in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

From that it is clear that Hulk didn't change into Banner since Avengers 2. Why is that? In previous films it is shown that Hulk can change back within a day or after a sleep.

In the movie Hulk is staying in a room with a swimming pool. He could have changed back to Banner anytime. But didn't, why?

And he didn't seem to remember anything happened in last 2 years, I wonder why?

Comment: People with multiple personalities aren't aware of the other personalities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of 2 reasons:

- The planet Sakaar is not safe and calm enough for Hulk to change into Banner. It's an environment with harsh condition near to death scenarios.
- Hulk and Banner are already separated minds. This version of Hulk displays more intelligence and speaks with more complex sentences. For that reason, Banner can't remember what happened in the last 2 years.

There are a few more reasons in [this source](https://www.quora.com/How-did-Banner-stay-as-the-Hulk-in-Thor-Ragnarok-for-so-long).

Comment: When he is Banner, the chaos and disruption all around him clearly agitates him. It was probably easier for Hulk to suppress puny Banner in that kind of setting.